# msa couldn't install error

Tags: updates, system-apps, redmi

I got a notification to install a system app **msa** update in my Redmi 4 Android Mobile. Whenever I'm trying to update the app it has been failing. I tried restarting my mobile as well but nothing worked.
What is the purpose of msa app and why it is not getting updated on my mobile.?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same issue in my xiao mi max 2. I have [read also this](http://en.miui.com/thread-2349460-1-1.html) maybe this will help you:

> On Mi Max 2 v9.5 MSA is not recognized as a system app for some reason. It is able to be uninstalled which is probably the reason for update error.
>
> On another Xiaomi phone I have. MSA is a system app and succesfully updated.
>
> MSA injects full screen advertisements into MIUI music player, themes + file explorer when you open them. I suggest you take advantage of this error by Xiaomi and uninstall MSA now then reboot your phone, full screen advertisements will be gone. If it updates you will be stuck with advertisements.